Which migration paths make sense to be enabled?
Quant.SE has finally graduated!  
This means that migration paths can be enabled and as indicated elsewhere a migration to Stats is a logical path. Could other migration paths also make sense?
Note that:

migration paths have to be approved--a demonstrated high volume of posts migrated and a low rejection rate generally lead to that approval.

Please, one migration path per answer.

Hi @BobJansen, Quant.SE is entitled to a migration path if it's needed, but as of right now, there are very few questions being migrated to Stats -- according to this page (disclaimer: viewable only to 10K rep users and mods), there's only been one migration to Stats.SE in the past 90 days. We look for a high rate of posts being sent to the other site with a low rate of rejection, otherwise things can get a little tense between the two communities.

Since we sometimes also receive programming  questions, I guess that a path to Stackoverflow would make sense as well.

Although it was already mentioned in the question, I am adding Cross Validated in the answers for clarity.

How about Economics SE? Questions pertaining to Economics rather than Finance pop up on our site from time to time.

This is true, but I haven't see too many redirects somehow.

I don't think this is possible as long as Economics is still a beta site. Migration paths to beta sites are only added in exceptional cases. (I don't know the volume of Migrations form Quant.SE to Economics, but it doesn't seem very large, so this is not an exceptional case)

I think we should also add Math for questions too specific on the fields and not directly applied to quantitative finance.

From the question: "Please, one migration path per answer." Note that Cross Validated was already mentioned in the question (as stats.SE, but that is the same site). Also, I don't think a migration path to Math.SE makes sense. There have been no migrations form Quant.SE to Math.SE in the last 90 days. It seems this is the last question that was migrated form Quant.SE to Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894908/brownian-motion-as-scaling-limit-of-random-walks

Ok I split the answers. I think more questions could actually be directed back to Math.SE and I don't see the harm in having a migration path anyway.
